# What's wrong with Geany?

Tags: c

```
#include <cini.h>

  int main() {
int a ;
a = 21 ;
printf(a);

return 0;
  }
```

Questions :
1) on the toolbar, once I've written the code, the "execute" or "compile" functions on Geany (a C compiler) seem to be disabled
2) what's wrong with my code ?
I'm about to learn C, so please be nice with a rookie.

Answer (score 2):

Geany is an editor, not a compiler. If the compile and execute functions are disabled it could be because it is unable to find your actual compiler (make sure you have one installed), or because you haven't saved your file as C code.

The first argument to `printf` must be the format string. If you want to print an integer as decimal, you need to use the `%d` conversion specifier, like this:

```
printf("%d\n", a);
```

The `\n` after the `%d` prints the linefeed character to the output. You can read about the `printf` function [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/printf.html).

You need to include at least `stdio.h`, because `printf` is declared in that header. The only reference I could find to `cini.h` was [this header here](https://code.google.com/p/cini/source/browse/cIni.h) which won't work in a C program because it is C++ code.